# How can I get a bigger reputation graph?

Tags: discussion, reputation-graph

I liked the reputation graph on the Activity tab in the user's profile. If you don't know what I mean, see this:

[image]

This graph is useful for me. However, it is very difficult to see exact changes even when zoomed extremely. How can I get a bigger graph of this?

Comment: Check the Reputation tab on the network profile, not on the SO profile. https://stackexchange.com/users/8318177/stevefest?tab=reputation.

Comment: @BhargavRao That is absolutely fantastic! You can make an answer :)

Comment: If you can live with some inaccuracies you could leverage the graphing capabilities of [SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234414/158100).

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it, just not all users think it is useful to have a discussion about your/the reputation graph or its size.

Comment: In what way is that not a freehand circle?

Comment: That line chart was made with D3 (an old version, by the way). It's quite easy to add a zoom feature to that chart, so the user can zoom in the line chart the way they want.

Comment: Excellent freehand circle. No wonder you've gained so many (non-applicable) reputation points from this.

Comment: This is a cross-site duplicate of [Graph of Reputation Over Time for all linked accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89429/graph-of-reputation-over-time-for-all-linked-accounts).

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You can use the [reputation tab on your network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=reputation), where there is a complete graph of your reputation on all sites where you have more than 200 reputation:

[image]

By default, the graph shows the complete curves, so that the time axis goes from when you first signed up on a Stack Exchange site to today and the reputation axis goes from 0 to your reputation on the site where you have the most reputation. If you want to see details, you can zoom in by dragging the mouse from to form a rectangle around the part you want to zoom in on:

[image]

If you do this, there is a Reset zoom button so that you can zoom out again.

Also, if you're just interested in one site at a time, you can click on the site name to the right of the graph to hide/show the graph for that specific site.

Comment: By the way, there is a UI error when I zoom like about ~9000% times bigger.

Comment: Actually it's throwing JS (highcharts) errors at normal zoom as well. But it's clearly bugging out after zooming in too much - like the date axis keeps resetting after a while if you keep zooming in.

Comment: Note that this is specifically the Stack Exchange profile page, and not your site specific profile page (e.g. the Stack Overflow one), as that shows a bar graph, not a line graph.

Answer (score 20):

Just click the mouse middle button over the "recent achievements" icon: (trophy)

[image]

Same as @DonaldDuck's accepted answer, just directly available on any SE site at one click. You can also [right-click --> open link in a new ...] of course if you do not have the middle button of the mouse.

---

PS:

This also delivers the *user ID* in the URL which you need to get your view / score question stats downloaded as csv, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/353892/787861). Such question stats are a nice complement to the curve when downloaded several times over time since question views are not stored. The stats are updated every Sunday.

---

PSS:

You can also get a graph over time using SEDE, meaning a query against the SE database, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234414/787861). But then you need the *user id* of the profile of each community site to give you a detailed graph. That cannot be done for all of your sites altogether. Example from the link:

[image]

For example, to get this for Stack Overflow, go to your profile page and copy the *user id* of that Stack Exchange. Query it and click on the graph tab. *(Credits go to the comment of @rene at the top.)*

Comment: links that act differently whether they are clicked in a window or sent to a new one completely mess my understanding of the universe.