# How can I see the all-time reputation graph of another user profile?

Tags: support, new-users, users, reputation-graph, top-users

When having a look at a profile of some long-time users, you do not see the full-scale interactive reputation graph.

- I think that the beginning even of a 12-years profile is interesting as well.
- On the one hand, it might be cut off for privacy reasons.
- On the other hand, for example, it helps to find out whether a user has just started in the last months but had a profile for much longer.
- Sometimes, second profiles with less activity get merged and decrease the "average points per year" or day or whatever. The reputation graph would show such a story a bit.

Is there a way to see the reputation graph over all time for a user profile that is not mine?

Comment: https://stackexchange.com/users/15462527/questionto42?tab=reputation? This works for any user who has a network account, which is the vast majority of them.

Comment: @CodyGray I remember having seen a graph that was cut off - but on the normal profile page, of course, therefore the question. I have found the all-time graph in the network profile now, you get there with:  
Drop-down `Profile` --> Tab `Reputation`. Good to know. And as to the close reason: I understood the duplicate [How to get a bigger reputation graph?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357554/how-to-get-a-bigger-reputation-graph) only as a graph of my own user profile, I did not think that I could see the network profile of every user.

Comment: It should work for every user. Is it not working for you? And the normal graph should never be cut off, although it is quite small for seeing trends at various time periods.

Comment: @CodyGray It is working. It is just that I had thought about it before asking here, and I could not imagine how I should enter another user's the network profile. I did not know about this `Profile` drop-down, and I also did not think that the link to the network profile could be there *inside* the "normal" user profile at all.

Comment: The reason why I never used that "Network Profile" drop-down even for myself and therefore did not know about it is that you get to your network profile when you [middle-click the badge symbol](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/367043/787861). And where should I do that on another one's profile... It is clear now.